# adjustPan not properly resizing screen

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a layout with Text,2 Spinners, 1 `EditText` and 1 Button on the end. When i want to enter something in `EditText` that button get covered by Keyboard.

This is `Fragment` not `Activity` if it's making any difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparentlightgrey">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/SectionName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"


                android:background="@color/neonGreen"
                android:textColor="#C6D600"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Add Credit"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AddPointsHolder"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinneroperater"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#d8d8d8"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerTopUp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"


                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#d8d8d8"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Enter Phone number"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="12"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/AddPointsHolder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/SectionName"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/addPoints"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addPoints"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_clickable"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Add Credit" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adjustPan` doesn't resize the screen. Since you have a scrolling view, you should be using `adjustResize`.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) on `adjustPan`:

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add Credit"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:textColor="@color/lightGrey"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/AddPointsHolder"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinneroperater"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#d8d8d8"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

               <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerTopUp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#d8d8d8"
                    android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

               <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
                    android:hint="Enter Phone number"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:maxLength="12"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/addPoints"
                android:id="@+id/AddPointsHolder"
                android:layout_below="@+id/SectionName"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add Credit"
                android:id="@+id/addPoints"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_clickable"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```